# IIS - Not serving my JS and CSS files over the internet

Tags: iis

I have got my website to work localhost on Windows Server 2019 dedicated IIS 10, but I am trying to reach my site on the internet using my IP address so like this:

http://142.11.195.158/ but my CSS file and JS files are not loading.

and is that why i cant load my CSS and JS files because I am using the IP address to view the website remotely?

I have allowed anonymous access to enabled to my Apppool aswel. my mime types are setup of having these files.

Where am i going wrong?

In my index page im loading the images as so:

```
  <img src="img/service-icon/diamond.png" alt="Service 1">
```

and

```
  <img class="slide-img" src="~/images/image3.png" alt="Slide 3" />
```

Im using MVC core 3.1

The files are pointing to here external files:

```
https://142.11.195.158/css/youtube.css
```

In my root folder in IIS the css and js files are inside wwwroot, this is how the website got published from visual studio, so my root is wwwroot and inside here is the published css an js files inside wwwroot

```
--wwwroot (website)
  --wwwroot
      css
      js
```

Static files is ticked also when i installed Web Server or IIS

Comment: The files are not loading due to error or because they are not found?

Comment: why is this working locally on my windows server 2019?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are including files or what the network logs are when you try to load the page so we don't really know at this point. You have given us nothing to debug the situation, just "not loading".

Comment: Looks like resources are requested via https which your site does not support. `https://142.11.195.158/css/style.css` fails but `http://142.11.195.158/css/style.css` works. You can see all the failed requests in the developer console.

Comment: im going to set up ssl to support https, im just taking each step by step. i had to setup alot on the webserver to get this far

Comment: shall i get the https setup, will this solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. If you want to use SSL you have to first setup SSL.

Comment: Open the browser side developer tools and see what errors/warnings in console and what error status codes from the server side. Tons can be analyzed in order to learn the actual cause.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the moment, you need to remove this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```